# Resetting HP-Elitebook with Bitlocker and BIOS password

Tags: bios, bitlocker, disk-encryption, reset

so my employment contract is over and I still got my Laptop (HP EliteBook 820 G3) which according to the contract is now mine. But it is encrypted using Bitlocker and has a BIOS password. I tryed to boot into it with a Linux-live USB stick but it wouldn't let me do that for some reason.

Does somebody know a way to reset the PC or flash a new operating system on it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If it's now yours, I'm sure the company would be happy to provide this information. I doubt it's really yours.

Comment: Agree with above comment: your company should be happy to provide this information. Our company also allows us to keep our PCs after they are decommissioned (they "sell" them to us, but the cost is minimal). Standard procedure is for IT desktop services to remove encryption and any company passwords.

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove the BIOS password would be to unplug the CMOS battery for a few minutes and then plug it back in. It's the small round coin cell battery that provides power to keep system clock running and basic BIOS settings when a device is powered off. Have a look for a "maintenance manual" for your laptop model for detailed instructions on how to access it (some disassembly will be necessary). Some motherboards have switches to clear the settings but accessing them on a laptop may be trickier. After that you should be free to format the drive to get rid of Bitlocker encryption and install an OS of your choice.